# ActiveRecord has_many :through duplicating counter caches on mass assignment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, has-many-through

It seems ActiveRecord's counter_cache feature can result in a counter cache being incremented twice. The scenario in which I am seeing this behavior is when I have two models that have a `has_many :through` relationship with each other through a join model (ie: `Teacher` has many `Student` through `Classroom`). When using the `has_many :through` generated methods to associate Teacher and Student directly (without manually creating the join record) the count goes up 2 times. Example: `teacher.students << Student.create(name: "Bobby Joe")` causes `teacher.students_count` to increment by 2.

Please help me find a solution that mitigates or eliminates this problem while allowing me to continue using built-in counter caching AND mass assignment through the `has_many :through` relation.

I have spent many hours looking for a solution and have extracted the problem out to a small test app which is the simplest failing example I could create. Any additional details needed to help me solve this should hopefully be below.

Example schema and models:

```
create_table :teachers do |t|
  t.string  :name
  t.integer :students_count, default: 0
  t.timestamps
end

class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :classrooms
  has_many :students, :through => :classrooms
end

create_table :students do |t|
  t.string  :name
  t.integer :teachers_count, default: 0
  t.timestamps
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :classrooms
  has_many :teachers, :through => :classrooms
end

create_table :classrooms do |t|
  t.references :teacher
  t.references :student
  t.timestamps
end

class Classroom < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student, :counter_cache => :teachers_count
  belongs_to :teacher, :counter_cache => :students_count
end
```

Here is a short rails console session showing the steps taken and the fact that rails is executing **two** updates to `teachers` to increment `students_count`:

```
1.9.2-p290 :001 > t = Teacher.create(name: "Miss Nice")
  SQL (9.7ms)  INSERT INTO "teachers" ("created_at", "name", "students_count", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Tue, 28 Feb 2012 03:31:53 UTC +00:00], ["name", "Miss Nice"], ["students_count", 0], ["updated_at", Tue, 28 Feb 2012 03:31:53 UTC +00:00]]
 => #<Teacher id: 1, name: "Miss Nice", students_count: 0, created_at: "2012-02-28 03:31:53", updated_at: "2012-02-28 03:31:53"> 
1.9.2-p290 :002 > t.students << Student.new(name: "Mary Ann")
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "students" ("created_at", "name", "teachers_count", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Tue, 28 Feb 2012 03:32:12 UTC +00:00], ["name", "Mary Ann"], ["teachers_count", 0], ["updated_at", Tue, 28 Feb 2012 03:32:12 UTC +00:00]]
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "classrooms" ("created_at", "student_id", "teacher_id", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Tue, 28 Feb 2012 03:32:12 UTC +00:00], ["student_id", 1], ["teacher_id", 1], ["updated_at", Tue, 28 Feb 2012 03:32:12 UTC +00:00]]
  SQL (0.2ms)  UPDATE "students" SET "teachers_count" = COALESCE("teachers_count", 0) + 1 WHERE "students"."id" = 1
  Teacher Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "teachers".* FROM "teachers" WHERE "teachers"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.1ms)  UPDATE "teachers" SET "students_count" = COALESCE("students_count", 0) + 1 WHERE "teachers"."id" = 1
  SQL (0.0ms)  UPDATE "teachers" SET "students_count" = COALESCE("students_count", 0) + 1 WHERE "teachers"."id" = 1
  Student Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "students".* FROM "students" INNER JOIN "classrooms" ON "students"."id" = "classrooms"."student_id" WHERE "classrooms"."teacher_id" = 1
 => [#<Student id: 1, name: "Mary Ann", teachers_count: 1, created_at: "2012-02-28 03:32:12", updated_at: "2012-02-28 03:32:12">]
```

I've put the entire test app on github if anyone would like to look closer (https://github.com/carlzulauf/test_app). I also created a unit test which demonstrates the issue and fails to pass (https://github.com/carlzulauf/test_app/blob/master/test/unit/classroom_test.rb)

Comment: Looks like this will be fixed by this PR: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/14849, hopefully it will be in rails 4.2.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So far my research has told me this is probably a bug. Here are some github issues already filed for this problem:

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3903

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3085

Apparently there is an undocumented automatic counter cache caused by has_many :through relations. So if `Teacher.has_many :students, :through => :classrooms` then `teacher.students << student` collection assignments already look for and increment `teacher.students_count` if that column exists.

If you add `Classroom.belongs_to :teacher, :counter_cache => :students_count` then an additional callback is triggered when the Classroom model is created, and the column gets incremented *twice*.

**Effective work around:** rename the counter cache columns to something else. `Student#teacherz_count` and `Teacher#studentz_count` were effective at allowing my [test case](https://github.com/carlzulauf/test_app/commit/707a33f948d5d55a8aa942e825841fdd8a7e7705) to pass.

https://github.com/carlzulauf/test_app/commit/707a33f948d5d55a8aa942e825841fdd8a7e7705

I haven't yet been able to find where the problem lies in the ActiveRecord code base, so I won't accept my own answer for a while in case someone knows why `has_many :through` works this way and where the offending code lives.

### Update

I believe I found the offending line of code. Commenting out this line resolves the problem:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/889e8bee82ea4f75adb6de5badad512d2c615b7f/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_through_association.rb#L53

I can't seem to get edge rails up and running so I can't submit a pull for this bug yet. If someone else is able, please do.

Finding the offending line allowed me to craft a more effective monkey patch in my test app that resolves the issue without renaming any columns.

https://github.com/carlzulauf/test_app/commit/3c421b035bd032b91ff60e3d74b957651c37c7fa

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Weird behaviour, what if I need to create directly a Classroom model with additional field like `floor` or `room_number`. The counter cache won't be calculated and I have to update in manually.